# pandas grouping by day of year (removing leap-days ) results in 366 results

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, leap-year

I am trying to get the min T of each day of the year, having data coming from a span of ten years. Firstly I remove the leap days ( I have tested that it works and there are 29-02) but when I group them and get the min temperature it results in 366 rows, and none of them is 0!

When I only group data from one year it results in 365 rows, I have tested it with leap years and non-leap years, all results in 365, the problem is putting together data from different years, always give me 366 rows. Any clue?

```
df = df[~df['Date'].str.endswith('02-29')]

# print(df.sort_values(by='Date'))
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
#I have also tried with this, same result
#df = df[~((df['Date'].dt.day==29)&(df['Date'].dt.month==2))]


temp_max = df[(df['Element'] == 'TMAX') & (df['Date'] > '01-01-2005') & (df['Date'] < '31-12-2014')].groupby(
    [df['Date'].dt.dayofyear]).agg(np.max)['Data_Value']
```

I firstly use the string function to remove the leap day and then convert it to datetime format, but that is working fine

from inputting this:

```
print(df.head())
print(len(df))
df = df[~df['Date'].str.endswith('02-29')]
print(df.head())
print(len(df))
```

I get this

```
            ID        Date Element  Data_Value
0  SPE00120107  2009-05-31    TMAX         313
1  SP000003195  2015-09-10    TMIN         174
2  SPE00120107  2015-08-02    TMIN         148
3  SPE00120107  2009-05-31    TMIN          99
4  SPE00120287  2010-12-17    TMIN         -55
47304
            ID        Date Element  Data_Value
0  SPE00120107  2009-05-31    TMAX         313
1  SP000003195  2015-09-10    TMIN         174
2  SPE00120107  2015-08-02    TMIN         148
3  SPE00120107  2009-05-31    TMIN          99
4  SPE00120287  2010-12-17    TMIN         -55
47280
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please show `df['Date'].head()` prior to `df = df[~df['Date'].str.endswith('02-29')]`

Comment: Also, type `df['Date'].dtype` and show us the output

Comment: This looks very much like a part of a homework assignment from the course Applied Plotting, Charting & Data Representation in Python offered by the University of Michigan on Coursera.

Answer (score 0):

day of year gives you the day of year in THAT year. If that year happens to be a leap year, then march 1st will give you 61 days regardless of what else is there in the dataset. The function does not add up days in your dataset to give you that amount (which is what it looks like you're assuming)